# How to shorten repetitive validation code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#add_product_form').on('submit',function(){
    if ($('#product_date').val() == '') {
        $('#product_date').addClass('border-danger');
    }else{
        $('#product_date').removeClass('border-danger');
    }
    if ($('#product_name').val() == '') {
        $('#product_name').addClass('border-danger');
    }else{
        $('#product_name').removeClass('border-danger');
    }
    if ($('#select_category').val() == '') {
        $('#select_category').addClass('border-danger');
    }else{
        $('#select_category').removeClass('border-danger');
    }
    if ($('#select_brand').val() == '') {
        $('#select_brand').addClass('border-danger');
    }else{
        $('#select_brand').removeClass('border-danger');
    }
    if ($('#product_price').val() == '') {
        $('#product_price').addClass('border-danger');
    }else{
        $('#product_price').removeClass('border-danger');
    }
    if ($('#product_quantity').val() == '') {
        $('#product_quantity').addClass('border-danger');
    }else{
        $('#product_quantity').removeClass('border-danger');
    }
 })
```

This is one form with many fields. How can we shorten this code? I have tried same code in vanilla Javascript and obviously it contains more lines of code. Is there any better way to write this type of code?

Comment: This kind of question is better asked at [codereview.SE]. Because is is about code optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to make a function for repetitive things like this:

```
function validate($selector) {
    $selector.toggleClass('border-danger', $selector.val() == '')
}

$('#add_product_form').on('submit',function(){
    validate($('#product_date'));
    validate($('#product_name'));
    validate($('#select_category'));
    validate($('#select_brand'));
    validate($('#product_price'));
    validate($('#product_quantity'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `each` loop.

Adding a common class to the elements would simplify initial selector or use something like `$(this).find(':input[required]').each...`

```js
$('#add_product_form').on('submit', function() {
  $('#product_date,#product_name,#select_category,#select_brand,#product_price,#product_quantity').each(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('border-danger', !this.value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to maintain a list of fields in your JavaScript, use the [required attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_required_attribute) and leverage this in your script. This also will leverage the browsers inbuilt validation. If you don't want to use the inbuilt validation you can use a different attribute as I've done below. If you want to use the normal `required` attribute, just use that instead of `data-custRequired`

```js
$("#form").submit(function() {
  var valid = true;
  $(this).find("[data-custRequired]").each(function() {
    var itemValid = true;
    if (this.tagName === "FIELDSET") {
      itemValid = $(this).find(":checked").length > 0;           
    }
    //Otherwise validate normally
    else {
      itemValid = $(this).val() !== ""      
    }
    
    $(this).toggleClass("danger-border", !itemValid );
    if(!itemValid) 
    {
      valid = false;
    }
  });
  console.log("Form Valid = " + valid);
  
  return false;
})
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.danger-border {
  border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <label>First Name <input type="input" name="firstName" data-custRequired /></label>
  <label>Last Name <input type="input" name="lastName" data-custRequired /></label>
  <label>Comment <input type="input" name="comment"></label>
  <fieldset data-custRequired>
    <legend>Can we contact you - required</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="contact"> Yes </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="contact">No </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="contact">Maybe </label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Vanilla Javascript**

Not a whole lot more needed

```js
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  var requiredElements = this.querySelectorAll("[data-custRequired]");
  var valid = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < requiredElements.length; i++) {
    var itemValid = true;
    var el = requiredElements[i];
    if (el.tagName === "FIELDSET") {
      itemValid = el.querySelectorAll(":checked").length > 0;
    } else {
      itemValid = el.value !== "";
    }

    //To support IE 10 we don't use the inbuilt toggle
    if (itemValid) {
      el.classList.remove("danger-border");
    } else {
      el.classList.add("danger-border");
      valid = false;
    }
  }

  console.log("Form Valid = " + valid);
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
})
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.danger-border {
  border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label>First Name <input type="input" name="firstName" data-custRequired /></label>
  <label>Last Name <input type="input" name="lastName" data-custRequired /></label>
  <label>Comment <input type="input" name="comment"></label>
  <fieldset data-custRequired>
    <legend>Can we contact you - required</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="contact"> Yes </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="contact">No </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="contact">Maybe </label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```